# Smallest finite group which cannot be decomposed into a solvable piece and a perfect piece

Tags: finite-groups, representation-theory

What is the smallest finite group $ G $ that is neither solvable-by-perfect
$$
1 \to G_{solvable} \to G \to G_{perfect} \to 1 
$$
nor perfect-by-solvable
$$
1 \to G_{perfect} \to G \to G_{solvable} \to 1 
$$

Obviously if $ G $ is perfect or solvable then it can be decomposed in both ways. The smallest group that is neither perfect nor solvable is $ S_5 $, but $ S_5=A_5.2 $ is perfect-by-solvable.

Context:
A lot of my intuition comes from Lie groups. Every Lie algebra has a maximal solvable radical. Using this, any Lie group $ G $ can be written as
$$
1 \to G_{solvable} \to G \to G_{semisimple} \to 1 
$$
in some ways semisimple Lie groups are like perfect finite groups (this analogy is explored in [Commutator of a connected semi simple Lie group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4439934/a-semi-simple-lie-group-whose-commutator-is-not-closed/4818278#4818278) and in [Is the fundamental group of a connected semisimple Lie group equal to its Schur multiplier?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4440879/is-the-fundamental-group-of-a-connected-semisimple-lie-group-equal-to-its-schur)). For Lie groups every group is solvable-by-semisimple, using the Levi decomposition. I was wondering how much quickly this idea of decomposing the group into a perfect and solvable part fails for finite groups.

Update, thanks to sTertooy (the comment I left below):

"oh I see. Another way to describe this is that the derived series of a finite group always terminates in a perfect group $ G^{(n)} $ for some minimal $ n $ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup for example where this fact is explicitly stated) indeed this $ G^{(n)} $ is the $ N $ you describe. Then $  G^{(n)}=N $ is normal because commutator subgroups are always characteristic and a characteristic subgroup of a characteristic subgroup is itself characteristic in the full group. Quotienting by $  G^{(n)}=N $ always gives a solvable group of derived length $ n $"

Summary of what I learned:

Every finite group is perfect-by-solvable because the derived series of a finite group always terminates by finiteness. In general, I think an abstract group is perfect-by-solvable if and only if the derived series terminates (in other words there exists an $ n $ such that $ G^{(n)}=G^{(N)} $ for all $ N \geq n $).

Many finite groups are not solvable-by-perfect, for example $ S_5 $ (the only solvable normal subgroup is $ 1 $ which does not have a perfect quotient).

Every Lie group is solvable-by-semsimple by the Levi decomposition.

Many Lie groups are not semisimple-by-solvable, for example any $ SE(n,\mathbb{R}) \cong \mathbb{R}^n \rtimes SO(n,\mathbb{R}), n \geq 3 $ since this Lie group is not solvable but its only semisimple normal subgroup is the trivial group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every finite group is perfect-by-soluble. To see this, let $G$ be a finite group and consider the set of normal subgroups of $G$ whose quotient is soluble. Let $N$ be minimal in this set.

The quotient $G/[N,N]$ fits in the short exact sequence
$$1 \to N/[N,N] \to G/[N,N] \to G/N \to 1.$$
Since both $N/[N,N]$ and $G/N$ are soluble, so is $G/[N,N]$. But $N$ is minimal among the normal groups with soluble quotient, so $N = [N,N]$ and hence $N$ is perfect.

Comment: oh I see another way to describe this is that the derived series of a finite group always terminates in a perfect group $ G^{(n)} $ for some minimal $ n $ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutator_subgroup for example where this fact is explicitly stated) indeed this $ G^{(n)} $ is the $ N $ you describe. Then $  G^{(n)}=N $ is normal because commutator subgroups are always characteristic and a characteristic subgroup of a characteristic subgroup is itself characteristic in the full group. quotienting by $  G^{(n)}=N $ always gives a solvable group of derived length $ n $